# CentOS 6: SATA link down when scanning for unused drives

Tags: linux, centos, raid, hard-drive, sata

I recently inherited a CentOS 6 server with 8 installed hard drives. 6 of these drives were going to be configured as an LVM, but never got that far. The drives are installed and, from what I can tell, healthy, but lsblk does not show them, nor does fdisk. The following shows up in dmesg when I grep for "ata":

```
EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
ioatdma: Intel(R) QuickData Technology Driver 4.00
EXT3-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
ata1: hard resetting link
ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata1: EH complete  
ata2: hard resetting link
ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata2: EH complete
ata3: hard resetting link
ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata3: EH complete
ata4: hard resetting link
ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata4: EH complete
ata5: hard resetting link
ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata5: EH complete
ata6: hard resetting link
ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata6: EH complete
```

I am completely unfamiliar with this error and I'm unsure what to do about it. /dev/sda and /dev/sdb are both SATA disks.

Here's the lsblk output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 930.4G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 927.9G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
```

Kernel version, if needed:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org)      (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 01:55:02 UTC 2014
```

Anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the BIOS settings to make sure the drives in question are active on the assigned SATA ports.

If this were a Dell server, I would suggest you boot to the BIOS and run the hardware drive diagnostics to see if the system is actually recognizing all the drives.